# Is it possible to use x:Shared attribute in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

When I try to use `x:Shared="False"` in my resources I got next error:

`Syntax Error found in XBF generation`

My element is contained in typical `ResourceDictionary`

So is it limitations of win8 or I do something wrong?

Comment: It's only available in WPF, but not in Windows Runtime or Silverlight.

Comment: @Clemens, thank you! Convert your comment to answer, please.

Comment: @Clemens, does it mean that all resources are shared?